# Ethernet switch and usb-hub in one device

Tags: usb, desktop, ethernet, hub, dvi

Want reduce the multiple devices&cables spaghetti on my desk. So, looking for an device with following (as most as possible) specification:

- 1-2 port Ethernet ports
- USB HUB (external powered!)

  - USB 3 and one USB-C
- maybe HDMI or DVI
- etc... :)

The best would be something which I could name as "**motherboard back-panel extender/hub**", e.g. something like in the following image, but in one compact the desktop device.

Or as an alternative, something like in the second image, but **also** with at least 1-2  Ethernet ports, and HDMI or DVI port.

[image]

[image: desk hub]

Comment: Wouldn't you be looking DVI and VGA or 2HDMI?  I could be wrong but I don't think even usb3.0 can push more then 2 monitors through their bandwidth.

Comment: What connectors do you have on the device you're plugging into? What's your budget? If you're going to be running all the cables independently anyways (as seems to be implied by the "extender" bit), why not just cable manage several of the same length?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the

http://www.targus.com/us/universal-usb-3_0-dv-docking-station-acp70usz

I think you are looking for port replicator or docking station. It is useful for laptops/tablets but for fixed PC the cable ties/velcro is better option. And probably a box to put the cables in ;)